# How to check inputs in a text file?

Tags: java

I want to read two integer values in a text file. I wrote `FileScanner` and other necessary parts but I want to check the contents.

For example in this file there should be two things like that:

`MAX=number1 MIN=number2`

I have to check a lot of situation like

1) MAX , MIN order. MIN or MAX value cannot be in the new line . Each of them should be ordered like that MAX,MIN
2) Integer values. For example `MAX:13 MIN:45A(Wrong number format)`

My question is that how can I seperate this `String ( MAX , MIN )` and integer values to check these kind of situations or should I seperate them for check their format?

Comment: Are you asking how to read text from a file or how to analyze it?

Comment: I know how to read values from a file but my problem is how to check file contents correct or not . So I think my problem is how to analyze file content

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  In general you should parse the format of a line first - and then parse values, and finally perform value validation.  I hate to give you this answer - but:   there are lots of examples "on the internet" about proper ways to parse text.

Comment: Thanks. In my question I asked should I seperate them? I mean should I parse them and looks like I should. I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   String filePathString="PATH"+fileName;
    File f = new File(filePathString);      
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {                
                scanFile = new Scanner (new File(fileN`enter code here`ame));
                okuyucu = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
            }   

    while(scanFile.hasNextLine()){
                    zz=scanFile.nextLine();
                    if(zz.contains("MAX")){
                        bir=true;
                        holder1[0]=zz;
                    }
                    if(zz.contains("MIN")){
                        iki=true;
                        holder1[1]=zz;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example here you can take the whole line with Scanner's nextLine() or BufferedReader's readLine(), and you'd end up with a String "MAX=number1 MIN=number2"

Notice that there's a space separating the two of them. If you're sure that there can't be any spaces in any other place, you can use String's split() method.

In code, it'd look like this:

```
String line = in.nextLine(); // Scanner input from text file
String[] array = line.split(" "); // split according to the space, you'll end up with "MAX=number1" and "MIN=number2"
```

Going further, to separate the MAX and MIN from their numbers, you can use split("="). You can figure out the rest.

Comment: I am sure there is no space except MAX=number1(here.) MIN=number2 .Thanks for help :)